# android- How to change viewpager views by button

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using viewPagerIndicator library . 
I want to put 2 button on each view on my viewPager . I've the buttons but I don't know how can I manually change the views .

one button moves the viewPager to left and brings next view and the other one moves to the right .

Answer (score 0):

For going right:

```
if(viewPager.getCurrentItem != number of pages -1){
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(++viewPager.getCurrentItem);
}
```

For going left:

```
if(viewPager.getCurrentItem != 0){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(--viewPager.getCurrentItem);
}
```